# Sprite moving using input coordinates

Tags: javascript, sprite, phaser-framework, tiled

```js
    /************ON RECEIVING MESSAGES VIA WEBSOCKET FROM THE SERVER********/
    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
     var mySpan = document.getElementById("messageGoesHere");
     var mySpan2 = document.getElementById("messageGoesHere2");
     var str = event.data;
     //var temp = new Array();
     //temp = str.split("\\|");
     /***********SPLITS THE RECEIVED MESSAGE****************
      *********AND STORES THE VALUE IN THE VARIABLES*********/
      if((str.localeCompare('connected'))==0)
      {
       document.getElementById("connection").innerHTML='Connected'; 
      }
      else if((str.localeCompare('closed'))==0)
      {
       document.getElementById("connection").innerHTML='No connection';
      }
     else{
       var array = str.split('|');
       mySpan.innerHTML = parseInt(array[5])
       mySpan2.innerHTML = parseInt(array[6]);  
       draw(parseInt(array[5]), parseInt(array[6]));
     }
    };
```

I am working on a robot game and I am using phaser library.My requirement is to pass the x y coordinates to robot(sprites) and it should move according to that coordinates without any velocity or speed. 
I am using following code for moving the robot. Now I want to move it on map using the incoming coordinates. So, kindly give me some suggestions.

```js
  // The following code is for the robot movement 
     
     // This is initial velocity
     player.body.velocity.x = 0;
        player.body.velocity.y = 0;

        if (cursors.left.isDown)
        {
            player.body.velocity.x = -200;
        }
        else if (cursors.right.isDown)
        {
            player.body.velocity.x = 200;
        }

        if (cursors.up.isDown)
        {
            player.body.velocity.y = -200;
        }
        else if (cursors.down.isDown)
        {
            player.body.velocity.y = 200;
        }
```

Comment: There's no question here, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I amgetting the coodinates in json format. Now I want to use that as a input coordinates to the sprite movement.

Comment: i think that will not require any speed or velocity. The problem is how can I implement this?

Comment: Please update your post with exactly what you're looking for. You need to get the values from JSON? Or do you just need to set the x/y values? `this.player.x = varX;` Also, you say you don't want any velocity, but then why is the code snippet 100% velocity manipulations?

Comment: Actually I am doing a simple project on robotics. I am getting the real time coordinates in Json format from robot. So now I want use that coordinates to show the real time robot movement.The  snippet I have tried for creating normal condition for sprite movement. But Now I want to use this sprites to move according to real time data.

Comment: Why don't you update the question with relevant code then? Like how are you streaming the JSON to your game?

Comment: Hello @JamesLowrey , sorry for my inconvenience. I am using the websocket...check this snippet.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Sorry I'm not trying to be condescending or anything, just trying to say that if you update your question than more people will be able to help. I don't see a link to a snippet. Maybe put it in your question instead?

Comment: Hey @JamesLowrey check the updated code and do help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it looks like your question is related to how to position the Sprite in the game world, using coordinates obtained from an external source - over the web. This is a problem in any multiplayer game. Basically, how do you position your players when your server's positions are inherently out of date to what your users are doing? [Here is a really good article from Valve on the subject](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Latency_Compensating_Methods_in_Client/Server_In-game_Protocol_Design_and_Optimization). You don't need to do all of that for a single player game that's just setting a position from a websocket. However, I would recommend saving the last 1 or 2 `last_positions` coordinates, and [lerping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) between them as you await the next value coordinate.

If your question is more related to how to get the coordinates from your external script into your Phaser game, then it looks like you are currently storing your WebSocket data into an HTML div? If that's the case, Phaser is still JS, and has the capability to interact with the DOM. In your `update()` function, access the element in the DOM and get your value.

Can't say that I'd recommend this approach though. I bet that writing/retrieving from the DOM will incur an I/O (maybe even some sort of re-render) penalty. Instead, I would recommend loading your game script before your websocket script, exposing a global `updateCoordinates(x,y)` function in your game, and using that callback from your websocket script. Then you can update your 1 or 2 `last_positions`, and in `update()` lerp between those positions.

```
//game.js, load before webSocket
var game = ... //global variable
//state 'PlayGame' is where your robot moves

//webSocket.js
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  ... 
  game.states.state.PlayGame.updateCoordinates(x,y);
}
```

Comment: you solved my problem, thanks for this explanation. But I have one small . How can I update my sprite position according updated coordinates.??

Comment: I'm glad you got it worked out! If you're using the `updateCoordinates` callback in the `onMessage` function, you should update the Sprite's position in there. Or, if you decide to do the lerping method, update `last_positions` in `updateCoordinates`, and set the Sprite's position in the `update()` function to be a lerp between the previous 2 x&y positions.

Comment: OK @James Lowrey. I will try this and I think this will solve my problems . I will let you know after completing my work. I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help. Hope it goes well!